# Rails optimization Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

In Rails while using activeRecord why are join queries considered bad.

For example

Here i'm trying to find the number of companies that belong to a certain category.

```
  class Company ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :company_profile
  end
```

Finding the number of Company for a particular category_id

```
number_of_companies = Company.find(:all, :joins=>:company_profile, :conditions=>["(company_profiles.category_id = #{c_id}) AND is_published = true"])
```

How could this be better or is it just poor design?

```
  company_profiles = CompanyProfile.find_all_by_category_id(c_id)
  companies = []
  company_profiles.each{|c_profile| companies.push(c_profile.company) }
```

Isn't it better that the first request creates a single query while i'd be running several queries for the second case.

Could someone explain why joins are considered to be bad practice in Rails

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add some references? I wasn't aware that such an opinion was generally held - AFAIK, it's something to avoid unless you need it but when you do need it (typically for performance reasons) then you should absolutely consider it - that's why it's there. That said, I think the specific example you give might possibly be most efficiently handled using count() with appropriate conditions. (If you only need a number, that is)

Comment: I seem to have found some help here 

http://akitaonrails.com/2008/05/25/rolling-with-rails-2-1-the-first-full-tutorial-part-2

Comment: It seems there is no general rule against using joins but when you have a lot of joins it implies that your associations aren't properly designed.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such rule. The rule is to hit the database as least as possible, and rails gives you the right tools for that, using the joins.

The example Sam gives above is exemplary. Simple code, but behind the scenes rails has to do two queries, instead of only one using a join.

If there is one rule that comes to mind, that i think is related, is to avoid SQL where possible and use the rails way as much as possible. This keeps your code database agnostic (as rails handles the differences for you). But sometimes even that is unavoidable.

It comes down to good database design, creating the correct indexes (which you need to define manually in migrations), and sometimes big nested structures/joins are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Join queries are not bad, in fact, they are good, and ActiveRecord has them at its very heart. You don't need to break into find_by_sql to use them, options like :include will handle it for you. You can stay within the ORM, which gives the readability and ease of use, whilst still, for the most part, creating very efficient SQL (providing you have your indexes right!)

Bottom line - you need to do the bare minimum of database operations. Joins are a good way of letting the database do the heavy lifting for you, and lowering the number of queries that you execute.

By the by, DataMapper and Arel (the query engine in Rails 3) feature a lot of lazy loading - this means that code such as:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@category.companies.size
```

Would most likely result in a join query that only did a COUNT operation, as the first line wouldn't result in a query being sent to the db.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the number of companies on a category all you need to do is find the category and then call the association name and size because it will return an array.

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@category.companies.size
```

Comment: I understand that, my question is aimed at understanding why join queries are considered bad. Im sorry if my question is not very clear.

Comment: I think you are making it harder than it is because quite simply joins are  adding twice the work where if you  stick with one model its half the work.

Comment: You should write `@category = Category.find(params[:id], :include => :companies)` or else you are hitting the database twice. Concerning your comment above: quite the opposite actually.

Comment: if he's looking for the size then the correct is actually doing @category.companies.count. Calling find with include will load all the companies as objects, which is not necessary.